# Is there an emacs mode that will show syntax hilighting when editing my .hgrc file?

Tags: emacs, mercurial

Emacs doesn't recognize the extension .hgrc, so it uses fundamental mode and all the text is black, including comments. Is there a good mode to use for editing .hgrc? And how would I configure emacs to use that mode automatically when I'm editing .hgrc?

**Learned so far from answers:**

`conf-mode` is the mode I want, and there are various ways to configure emacs to use it for editing `.hgrc`.

Answer (score 6):

I added

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/\\.[^/]*rc" . conf-mode) t)
```

to my `.emacs.el`, so 
my emacs opens all RC files (including `.hgrc`) in `Conf[Unix]` mode.

The reason for the 3rd argument to [`add-to-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) is that the default mode for run control files is [`conf-mode`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/textmodes/conf-mode.el) unless a prior setting overrides it.

Answer (score 2):

Visit `.hgrc`, switch to Conf Mode with `M-x conf-mode`, and then type `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line RET mode RET conf-mode`.

This adds a special comment at the beginning of your `.hgrc`, which tells Emacs to use `conf-mode` for this file:

```
# -*- mode: conf; -*-

[extensions]
hgext.color =
# …
```

Comment: The special comment line works. I just typed it, saved, and did `m-x revert-buffer`. This solution is good for `.hgrc` since it's never checked in to a shared repo where the line would bother non-emacs users. Amusing that the command to add the comment line is more keystrokes than typing out the line. Oh emacs :)

Comment: @dinosaur For me, the keystrokes are just `M-x aflp RET m RET RET`, thanks to fuzzy completion from SMex and IDO, and you'd bind that command to a key when using it frequently.  Anyway, there's nothing wrong in just typing the line.  I used the command because it's unambiguous, and avoids any confusion from types and the like.